# r dplyr filter: regexp to exclude AND match

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, grepl

**Context:** Using `dplyr` and `filter`, exclude (Windows) the version of a filename entry indicating it is in use, but keep undecorated version of that filename.

I'd like to:

- Exclude list entries that contain "/~$"
- AND Select entries that end with `"__MATCH__9999.xlsx"` where `9999` can be any number of random integers.

**Input:** NOTE the first two entries refer to the same file

```
 fl=tibble(fn=c("C:/a/b/c/~$a__01__IQ9__FQ__MATCH__4567.xlsx",
      "C:/a/b/c/a__01__IQ9__FQ__MATCH__4567.xlsx",
      "C:/a/b/c/a__01__IQ2__FQ__NOTMATCH__8910.xlsx"))
fl %>%
  filter(grepl("regexp",fn))
```

**Desired result :**

```
"C:/a/b/c/a__01__IQ9__FQ__MATCH__4567.xlsx"
```

**Partial/Hack** I'm not sure how to reduce this two step into one....

```
> fl %>% 
  filter( grepl("(__MATCH__[\\d]+\\.xlsx$)",fn,perl=TRUE) ) %>%
  filter( !grepl("\\$",fn,perl=TRUE) )

# A tibble: 1 x 1
                                         fn
                                      <chr>
1 C:/a/b/c/a__01__IQ9__FQ__MATCH__4567.xlsx
```

Comment: Are trying to do `filter(grepl("^(?!.*/~\$).*__MATCH_\\d+\.xlsx$",fn))`?

Comment: Possibly? That regexp returns 0 rows after correcting the escape characters.

Comment: I'm not an R guru but found that grepl default engine doesn't support lookaheads. So [`perl` should be set as default](http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/grepl.php): `filter(grepl("^(?!.*/~\\$).*__MATCH_\\d+\\.xlsx$",fn, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = TRUE))`

Comment: `fl %>% filter(grepl("^(?!.*/~\\$).*__MATCH__\\d+\\.xlsx$",fn, perl=TRUE))` will work. revo missed one `_` after `MATCH`.

Comment: revo if you post a working version of that I'll be able to accept as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling `perl` as default engine, you are able to work with lookaheads:

```
fl %>% 
  filter(grepl("^(?!.*/~\\$).*__MATCH__\\d+\\.xlsx$",fn, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = TRUE))
# A tibble: 1 x 1
                                         fn
                                      <chr>
1 C:/a/b/c/a__01__IQ9__FQ__MATCH__4567.xlsx
```

Breakdown:

- `^`  Assert beginning of input string
- `(?!.*/~\\$)` Shouldn't contain `/~$`
- `.*__MATCH__\\d+\\.xlsx` Match this literal
- `$`  That occurs at the end